# How to make the layout move up and down

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a custom view that extends LinearLayout and is placed at bottom of a `RelativeLayout`. Now, I want to add an animation to it that make it move from bottom of its parent to its correct place and another animation to make it invisible by moving toward the bottom of the parent. (This animation triggers with `onTouch` event).

The layout that needs the animation is depicted as a purple media controller in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple translate animation and name it e.g. "anim/emerge.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="600"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

And then

```
Animation emerge = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.emerge);
_yourview_.startAnimation(emerge);
```

Comment: You made my day man. Thank you. I did the opposite as well (It seems that I should set the visibility of my view to GONE in that case)